# When the user of a shell is `root`, does running `su` on another user name ask for password of the other user?

Tags: linux, su, shadow-utils

When the user of a shell isn't `root`, running `su` on another user name will ask for password of the other user.

When the user of a shell is `root`, running `su` on another user name doesn't ask for password of the other user. Is it correct?

I searched in the manpage of `su`, which only says `su` would ask for the password of the other user, and doesn't say that it doesn't ask if the current user is `root`. Am I missing something from the manpage?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Could you be specific what PAM configuration?  Does that PAM configuration only apply to `su`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `/etc/pam.d/su` contains the following:

```
auth            sufficient      pam_rootok.so
```

then `root` is unilaterally allowed to use `su` without further authentication.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain why that line means "allows root to su without passwords"?

Comment: The `pam.conf(5)` man page explains `auth` and `sufficient`, and the `pam_rootok(8)` man page explains `pam_rootok.so`. Put succinctly... well, my answer puts it succinctly.