# How to make sudo not expire while script is running

Tags: sudo

I sometimes need to run a script for hours at a time, during which some commands need `sudo`. However, if I don't check and reenter the `sudo` password periodically, I get the `sudo: timed out reading password` error which sometimes breaks the whole thing. I don't want to use `sudo myscript.sh` since some of the commands should be run *without* `sudo`.

I'd like the `sudo` cached password to persist for the script for the whole duration of the script without changing the rest of the system (`sudo` persistence *only* for this 1 script).

Is there a way to make `sudo` last for the whole duration of the script and only for the 1 script?

Comment: Have you considered adding these commands in the `sudoers` file so password is not needed?

Comment: @Fiximan The commands I'm running can sometimes be dangerous if added with `NOPASSWD`. Most of the time, it's `nmap -sS` but something like `chmod` should not be enabled with `NOPASSWD`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change sudo timeout](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/579445/how-do-i-change-sudo-timeout)

Comment: @ajgringo619 No, it doesn't. The OP only wants to affect commands run by the script, but not the same commands when run outside of the script.

Comment: @ajgringo619 No. I only want to temporarily disable the timeout for the duration of the script without making permanent changes to `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

Possibility: run the script with `sudo myscript.sh`. Inside the script run commands that should be run without `sudo` this way:

```
sudo -u "$SUDO_USER" foo args
```

(maybe with proper logic in case the entire script is ever run without `sudo`). [The root user does not need to authenticate for `sudo`, and as such is not required to enter a password to run a command as another user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/445706/108618).

Depending on how big the script is (how much you need to change it) and how you feel about running the whole thing with `sudo` you may like or not like the idea. In your current approach non-elevated code is the default, lines with `sudo` being explicit exceptions. My approach turns this upside down. You need to be more careful when creating and testing the script. I admit this is not the best practice; still it solves the problem of expiring `sudo`.

Personally I would use this solution for a long running script that is not too complicated (simple loop, few commands). I would think twice before rebuilding a complicated script though.

---

Another approach is to periodically update the cached credentials in the background. By default these are per tty (see [`tty_tickets`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html#Boolean)). Proceed like this:

```bsh
sudo -v                              # to enter your password once
while sleep 300; do sudo -v; done &  # adjust the interval if needed
myscript.sh
```

Don't forget to kill the background job when no longer needed. The script itself can start such job; then you will probably want some traps in the script to kill the job automatically when the script terminates.